# Implementing Multiplayer

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I am making a multiplayer game with blender, well intending on doing so.
Can anyone set me out the tutorials I'm going to need for this project intended on. I want it done by direct IP for you to join friends (so you host your own server).

I don't need tutorials on how to build functions or whatever, just need help to understand how to make the game multiplayer and the rest I should be able to do on my own.
I'd prefer no python coding, but that is imply impossible :P 
Thank you for whoever can help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xZRfzOtxzA) should set you up. Check out the other tutorials too if it's too much programming at once, he explains it very nicely I think.

The programming itself isn't very difficult either, to set up a super basic multiplayer you only need very few lines of code, but how they interact with the rest of the game will take a bit of thinking. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

There is an addon for BGE made by agoose that has a multiplayer setup. I suggest you have a look at that and see if it provides an easy solution for you.

---

This is similar to the question "how do I carve a statue in wood - without using my hands". Multiplayer is not something you can implement in a few hours, or even a few days. A good multiplayer setup requires an understanding of a range of topics from advanced programming concepts through to the network stack and even some physics (and AI for more advanced lag compensation techniques).

So that this answer isn't completely useless as an answer, I will continue.

Networking in python is done typically through the `socket` module, though other frameworks such as `twisted` are available. Because blender python scripts have to run inside a frame, typically ports have to be used in non-blocking mode, or a multithreaded system set up.

You also have to design the architecture of the system. Do you have a game instance that is the "true" state of the game and all the clients are just interfaces to it? Do you have purely client-side calculations and only send updates to what a player does? There are many more architectures around, have a read and take a pick.